# CSS not working salesforce LWC in scratch org

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, scratch-org

I have created an LWC component and tested on local server. It was working fine. But when I deployed it to my *scratch org*, the code is working fine but CSS is not working. Below is my code for the LWC component

**The Css file::**

```
    .list-first {
    border-top: 1px solid #706e6b;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.list-last {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #706e6b;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**The HTML file::**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title='HelloIterator'>
        <ul>
            <template iterator:it={details}>
                <li key={it.value.Id}>
                    <div if:true={it.first} key={it.value.Id} class = 'list-first'></div>
                    {it.value.name}, {it.value.designation}
                    <div if:true={it.last} class='list-last'></div>
                </li>
            </template>
        </ul>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**The JS file ::**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class HelloIterator extends LightningElement {
    details = [{Id: '003171931112854375',name: 'Amy Taylor', designation : 'VP of engineering'},
    {Id: '003171931112854377',name: 'Michael Jones', designation : 'VP of Sales'},
    {Id: '003171931112854366',name: 'Jennifer', designation : 'CEO'}
    ];
}
```

the screenshot from the local serve is
[image]

and from the scratch org, the component seems to missed the CSS effects:*(without the border lines)*

[image]

Can anyone suggest what should i check here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what to say, exactly. It's working in webcomponents.dev, too: [link](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/l3Ga0CGVZQtsfTlatXoC). It may be other, more specific CSS is being applied, so you might need to crank up the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) by adding additional selectors to your style. You will want to inspect your component (right-click, Inspect Element), and then take a look at the elements generated and their calculated CSS. In most browsers, you'll see all the rules that affect an element in order of specificity, as well as which values are being overridden (shown by a "<strike>striked-out</strike>" font) to see what's causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox . I'll try to go through the specificity and see if i can get it work.